# DotnetCore app running within Docker on Amazon Linux multidocker container returns an error during Sql Server login process

Tags: sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I have a DotnetCore application (*DotNetCore v1.1*) running on Docker within an Amazon Linux instance (*64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.5.2 running Multi-container Docker 1.12.6 (Generic)*).

When I try to connect to my *Sql Server 2014 (Cumulative Update 2)*, I get an exception

```
Exception:   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Send(SNIPacket packet)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

**Things I have tried**

1. The port 1433 can be reached from docker container running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk app and a connection to the server can be established.
2. The Docker container containing the app when run on a Mac can connect to the same SQL Server.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of what was going on there? I'm seeing the same thing (other than different versions of the hosts/servers).

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing.